# How to disable memory limits in Magick++

Tags: imagemagick, magick++

How to disable any memory limits in Magick++? I don't want to have any limits, I'd prefer std::bad_alloc on memory exceeds.

I tried.

```
Magick::InitializeMagick( nullptr );
Magick::ResourceLimits::memory( 0 );
Magick::ResourceLimits::map( 0 );
```

But Magick++ ignores it.

These static methods receives unsigned values, and I tried big enough values, like 9999999999, but Magick++, as said, ignores them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you would be able to disable the resource limits as it's fundamental to the `MagickCore` library.

> I tried big enough values, like 9999999999, but Magick++, as said, ignores them.

During the genesis routines, the systems maximum limits are identified, then further reduced based on security policies (policy.xml), and [environmental variables](https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#environment). Attempting to set memory at any value greater then what is identified during geniuses would be ignored. Ideally Magick++'s `Magick::ResourceLimits::....` setters should return a boolean on success; thus, matching MagickCore's behavior.

> I don't want to have any limits, I'd prefer std::bad_alloc on memory exceeds.

Although I agree with you that it would be nice to rely on C++ standards, I doubt `std::bad_alloc` would be issued correctly. The core library does a good job balancing large streams/buffers of data between temporary, cache, and memory resources. If, somehow, you could disable limits in the core library, then this balance would be thrown off, and I would suspect that this would cause way more false-negative exceptions.

Comment: Not sure that Magick++ works correctly with balancing memory/disk/cache, as on opening GIF with ~500 frames of ~1900x1000 size only first ~35 frames coalesced correctly, all other frames are out of pixel cache and no one operation with frames, like crop, can be done - exception that pixel cache is exhausted. So where is the balance? I can't open ~1MB GIF with Magick++!

Comment: Wow. A gif that size could easily decode to a few dozen GB of authenticated pixel data (assuming Q16 * RGBA * width * height). You better move over to IM's [community forums](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/) and chat with the developers there. Disabling limits would not solve that problem.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the forum. I created [topic about this question](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=34980)

Comment: Magick++ uses policy.xml configuration file, I just edited it to have enough resources for ImageMagick and now such big GIF opens. Thanks to ImageMagick forum for the explanations.

Comment: Correct, your C++ can only reduce the value defined in policy.xml, never extend it.